# C++ check if a template argument is a function of a specific type

Tags: c++, function, templates

I've got the following function used as a bisection method

```
template <typename T>
float bisect(T value, float min, float max, float tol) {
    constexpr bool is_function1 = is_numeric_function1<T>::value;
    constexpr bool is_function2 = is_numeric_function2<T>::value;

    std::cout << is_function1 << " " << is_function2 << std::endl;
    
    if(is_function1) {
        ...
    } else if(is_function2) {
        ...
    }

...
}
```

At the beginning, I want to check if the first argument is a function of type `float(float)` or `float(float, float)` so I have the following template

```
template<typename T, typename = T> struct is_numeric_function1 : std::false_type {};
template<typename T>
struct is_numeric_function1 <typename T,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, float(float)>::value, T>
> : std::true_type {};

template<typename T, typename = T> struct is_numeric_function2 : std::false_type {};
template<typename T>
struct is_numeric_function2 <typename T,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, float(float, float)>::value, T>
> : std::true_type {};
```

For a function like this one

```
float f2(float v1, float v2) {
    return std::pow(v1, 2) + std::pow(v2, 2);
}
```

And the call like this

```
std::cout << bisect(f2, 0., 100, 1.)
    << std::endl;
```

The output is always

```
0 0
<result>
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: Does `is_numeric_function1` work? Also, please show how you're calling `bisect`.

Comment: None of the functions work, also I updated the question.

Comment: I can't [reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/vbPczPTY5).

Comment: Do you really want to deduce structs? You may create 1 struct with arg `enum {fun1, fun2} type` and set type in constructor.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't pass stateful objects to your `bisect` (I've seen none in your examples), simple function pointers and overloads do the job (I've simplified the snippet to focus on the main part):

```
float bisect(float fn(float)) { return fn(1); }
float bisect(float fn(float, float)) { return fn(1, 2); }

float f1(float x) { return x; }
float f2(float x, float y) { return x + y; }

int main() { std::cout << bisect(f1) << '\n' << bisect(f2) << '\n'; }
```

However, if you *do* need `T` to be something like stateful lambdas, simply [constrain](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) the more desired overload; in the following example I assumed it to be `float(float, float)`:

```
float bisect(auto&& fn) { return fn(1.f); }
float bisect(auto&& fn) requires requires { fn(1.f, 2.f); } { return fn(1.f, 2.f); }

int main() {
  std::cout << bisect([state = 42](float x) { return x; }) << '\n' << bisect(f2) << '\n';
}
```

Note: I suggest leaving the less prioritized overload unconstrained to allow passing overloaded functional objects like this one:

```
struct Overloaded {
  float operator(float) { return 42; }
  float operator(float, float) { return 42; }
} bisect_me_and_get_ambiguity;
```